# Norton 360 may be blocking command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, norton-360

on my 3 month old Windows 10 laptop, I kept seeing this error when using the Citrix client, and when I recently tried to launch the command prompt (as regular user and as admin), it shows the same error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142).  Click OK
> to close the application.

With technical support's help, using msconfig, I disabled all of the non-Microsoft services, rebooted, and then the command prompt worked.  Re-enabling them blocked it again.  I stopped the non-Microsoft services one by one and it was still failing.  The only service I couldn't stop from Windows Services was Norton Security service.

Therefore, I suspect that it's Norton 360 that's blocking cmd.exe from being launched by me or another application.  I did a full system scan and no issues were found.

Other things that I tried that didn't work:

Disable Smart Firewall via Norton 360 > Settings > Firewall > General Settings

Add cmd.exe and select 'Allow' under Norton 360 > Settings > Firewall > Program Control

Disable Automatic Program Control  via Norton 360 > Settings > Firewall > Automatic Program Control

So, if anyone else have any suggestions, I would be glad to hear it, and as always, all of the help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Niraj

Comment: Who owns the laptop?  You or a company?  If you, uninstall Norton completely, restart and then ensure Windows Defender is running. WD is top rated and better than Norton Consumer AV/

Comment: "Therefore, I suspect that it's Norton 360 that's blocking cmd.exe from being launched by me or another application. I did a full system scan and no issues were found."  and "The only service I couldn't stop from Windows Services was Norton Security service." doesn't jive.  If the only service you couldn't stop was Norton Security, and it worked when it was enabled, but all other non-Microsoft services were disabled then it couldn't be Norton Security causing the error.  Of course, I could be reading what you did entirely wrong.

Comment: Hi John, it's a personal laptop, and that was a great suggestion, I can reinstall it in the future.  HI Ramhound, thanks for your suggestion.  The issue resolved itself after the latest Wndows update was installed, plus the usual periodic Norton patches.